# Spring Many to one in json

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Hello is it possible to add mapped value in json?

Product entity

```
@Id
@Column(unique = true)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
@Column(unique = true)
private String title;
private String description;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Options> options= new ArrayList<>();
```

Option entity

```
    @Id
    @Column(unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Product product;
    private BigDecimal price=new BigDecimal(0);
    private BigDecimal discount=new BigDecimal(0);
```

What i get is

```
        {
            "id": 2,
            "price": 300.00,
            "discount": 35.00
        },
```

What i want is

```
    {
        "id": 2,
        "price": 300.00,
        "discount": 35.00,
        "product":[
          "id": 2,
          "title": "dsfa",
          "description": "dsfa",
          ....
        ]
    },
```

I want to add product to json response, how can i achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried removing @JsonIgnore ?

Comment: Use `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"options"})` instead `@JsonIgnore` on `product` field in Option class

Comment: The relation mapping that's correct. I think that you shouldn't return model as DTO  directly, that causes by infinite loop when Jackson convert object to Json. You should define DTO with fields that you want to return to client via response without need using annotation @JsonIgnoreProperties({"options"}) or  @JsonIgnore in both Entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just use `@JsonIgnoreProperties`.

```
@Id
@Column(unique = true)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
@Column(unique = true)
private String title;
private String description;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"product"})
private List<Options> options= new ArrayList<>();
```

and second class:

```
@Id
@Column(unique = true)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"options"})
private Product product;
private BigDecimal price=new BigDecimal(0);
private BigDecimal discount=new BigDecimal(0);
```

You will avoid the infinity loop in json result and get all reference objects (relationships).

Answer (score 1):

One Product have many Option or viceversa?
In your code one Product have many Option.

But if the relation is correct, the better way to get a custom result is with DTOs.

With DTO you can create a custom Class with all the details you need, example:

ProductDTO

```
private Integer id;
private String title;
private String description;

getter / setter
```

OptionDTO

```
private Integer id;
private BigDecimal price=new BigDecimal(0);
private BigDecimal discount=new BigDecimal(0);
private List<Product> products;

getter / setter
```

Soo, first retrieve with you service and reposity you data, then you set the DTO.

After you can send you data and get your custom Json.